# PyCharm: Can't enter AltGr keys on a french keyboard

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, pycharm

I installed the 2019.1 community edition of PyCharm on a Windows 10 Pro yesterday.
Everything works perfectly except that I cannot type `#`, `[`, or `]`.

I use a French keyboard, and these keys are accessed with a combination of <kbd>AltGr</kbd> and an upper row digit (for example, <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> is `#`). This works in all other programs except PyCharm.

Copy and pasting these into PyCharm works, but it's very tedious.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A workaround from [this issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-34912#focus=streamItem-27-3366742.0-0):

- Under Help|Find action, type 'registry'
- The first hit is 'Registry...', click it
- You must see the a key-value panel, uncheck the 'actionSystem.force.alt.gr' item

Comment: Bravo! This worked perfectly for me. Thanks! Left a +1 which will register once I have enough karma :)

Comment: Removing the marking in actionSystem.fix.alt.gr also did it for me.

Answer (score 0):

With the new version 2019.1.1 JetBrains fixed the issue. [This is the link to the release notes.](https://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2019/04/pycharm-2019-1-1/)
I restored the 'Registry...' to  defaults and all combinations with the <kbd>AltGr</kbd> key still work fine with version 2019.1.1.

Using a German keyboard layout, I was affected by the issue, too.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same/similar issue (AltGr key didn't work anymore in PyCharm with my German keyboard, so I couldn't type things like `[]` or `{}`)

My solution was similar to LaManoServidas answer, only difference:

- I had to *check* the 'actionSystem.force.alt.gr' item. It was unchecked, but when I checked it, my problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

With the version 2019.2 (2019-07-23), the [workaroud](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JBR-1744) is :

- use Ctrl-Alt instead of AltGr, or
- switch boot JDK to this [JBR 8 build (1483.58)](https://bintray.com/jetbrains/intellij-jbr/download_file?file_path=jbrsdk-8u202-windows-x64-b1483.58.tar.gz). See [manual](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/switching-boot-jdk.html) on how to switch

You can check what boot JDK is used in "Help | About".